# Using a variable as class name

Tags: php, class, yii

I have the following:

```
User::model()->exists($someParamsHere);
```

Is there a way to make the class name 'User' dynamic? So something like this:

```
$className::model()->exists($someParamsHere);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I also read something about the ReflectionClass, but i'm not really sure how to use it.

I tried this, but off course the model() method is never called this way:

```
$reflectionMethod  = new ReflectionMethod($className, 'exists');
$reflectionMethod->invoke(null, $someParamsHere);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$className::model()` works with PHP 5.3 and above, if I'm not mistaken. A workaround is to use `CActiveRecord::model($className)`. See the documentation for [CActiveRecord.model()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#model-detail).

Comment: My mistake! I used $this->className as the variable, but it gives an error on the '->'. Putting this in another variable works. `$className = $this->className;` and then `$className::model()->exists();`. Great answer though.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP >= 5.3 works fine:

```
<?php
class Foo {

    static function Bar() {
        return "Bar";
    }

    static function getFoo() {
        return new static();
    }

    function getBar() {
        return static::Bar();
    }
}

$class = "Foo";

print $class::Bar() . "\n";

print $class::getFoo()->Bar() . "\n";
```

Result:

```
Bar
Bar
```